# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "/": syntax error

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database, sqlite

How do i divide 2 different fields which sets a value to another field in sqllie3

```
cursor.execute(f"UPDATE main SET W/L Ratio = Wins/Loss WHERE Players = {int(winner_id)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a name that has non-standard characters.  I would recommend naming the column as something like `win_loss_ratio`.  Then it would not need escaping.

But if you have no control over this, then you need to use double quotes (or perhaps square braces):

```
SET "W/L Ratio" = Wins / Loss
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing your quotations

```
cursor.execute(f'UPDATE main set "W/L Ratio" = Wins/Loss WHERE Players = {int(winner_id)}')
```